# Conditionally concatenate variable names into a new variable in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string, if-statement, concatenation

I have a data set with 3 columns and occasional NAs. I am trying to create a new string column called 'check' that will concatenate the name of the variables that don't have an NA in each row in between underscores ('_'). I pasted my code below as well as the data that I have, the data that I need and what I actually get (See the hyperlinks after the code). For some reason, it seems the conditional that I have in place is completely ignored and the example_set['check'] =  example_set['check'] + column is executed at every loop with or without the conditional code block. I assume there is a Python/Pandas quirk that I haven't fully comprehended... Can you please help?

```
example_set = pd.DataFrame({

                        'A':[3,4,np.nan]
                        ,'B':[1,np.nan,np.nan]
                        ,'C':[3,4,5]

                            }
                          ) 
example_set

columns = list(example_set.columns)

example_set['check'] = '_'

for column in columns:
    for row in range(example_set.shape[0]):
        if example_set[column][row] != np.nan:
            example_set['check'] =  example_set['check'] + column
        else:
            continue

example_set
```

[Data that I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tC7KH.png)

[Data that I was hoping to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zL2vQ.png)

[What I actually get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfqiX.png)

Comment: Hi Welcome to SO. Thank you for the clear content of the question. The title is a little misleading though. You might want to change it to something like 'how to get column names for not nan cells' to have more answers if you don't prefer mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the rows that have null values, iterate the values with [numpy compress](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.compress.html), get the [difference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) of the iteration from the columns, format the strings to your taste and create a new column:

```
columns = example_set.columns

example_set['check'] = [f'_{"".join(columns.difference(np.compress(boolean,columns)))}_' 
                        for boolean in example_set.isna().to_numpy()]

     A   B  C   check
0   3.0 1.0 3   _ABC_
1   4.0 NaN 4   _AC_
2   NaN NaN 5   _C_
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest strategy is to copy df. Create a new column in it. Iterate over the rows of the old df, filter for nan cells then get the remaining indices.
Join them in a string and put those values to new df.
It is probably not the most efficient method, but it should be easy to understand.

Here is some code to get you going:

```py
nset = example_set.copy()
nset["checked"] = "__"
for s in range(example_set.shape[0]): 
    serie = example_set.iloc[s] 
    nserie = serie[serie.notnull()]
    names = "".join(nserie.index.tolist())
    nset.at[s, "checked"] = "__" + names + "__"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
import numpy as np
example_set = pd.DataFrame({

                        'A':[3,4,np.nan]
                        ,'B':[1,np.nan,np.nan]
                        ,'C':[3,4,5]

                            }
                          ) 
example_set['check'] = '_ABC_'
for i in range(len(example_set)):
    list_ = example_set.iloc[i].values.tolist()
    if math.isnan(list_[0]):
        example_set['check'][i] = example_set['check'][i].replace('A','')
    if math.isnan(list_[1]):
        example_set['check'][i] = example_set['check'][i].replace('B','')
    if math.isnan(list_[2]):
        example_set['check'][i] = example_set['check'][i].replace('C','')
```

Output:

```
A   B   C     check
0   3.0 1.0 3   _ABC_
1   4.0 NaN 4   _AC_
2   NaN NaN 5   _C_
```